# Installing Informix Client SDK on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, sdk, arm, raspberry-pi, informix

I wanted my raspberry pi to connect to an Informix database thru Python.
I tried installing the [InformixDB module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/informixdb/) for python but I get an error as

> NameError: name 'arch_' is not defined

But this is caused because I didn't have an Informix Client SDK installed on the pi which does the underlying work of connecting to the DB and the module is just a wrapper. I searched the [IBM downloads](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?rs=ifxdl) but couldn't find the package for ARM architecture.

I've also tried the following links but to no good. 
https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/
https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/wiki/README

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading the Informix Developer Edition for Raspberry Pi. It contains the engine and the client.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The Informix Developer Edition for Raspberry Pi had the Client SDK as part of the package which is exactly what I was looking for.