# Unable to install IBM_DB in Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install ibm_db on my raspberry pi with raspbian. I've been trying with many methods but non one has worked, I always get this output :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# pip2 install ibm_db
Downloading/unpacking ibm-db
Downloading ibm_db-2.0.6.tar.gz (552kB): 552kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-nzFdb7/ibm-db/setup.py) egg_info for package ibm-db
Detected 32-bit Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-nzFdb7/ibm-db/setup.py", line 149, in <module>
    easy_cli_path = os.path.join(tmp_path, 'ibm_db-%s.egg' % ("-".join([VERSION, "py"+sys.version.split(" ")[0][0:3]]) if('win32' in sys.platform) else "-".join([VERSION, "py"+sys.version.split(" ")[0][0:3], os_, arch_])), 'clidriver')
NameError: name 'arch_' is not defined
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Detected 32-bit Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build-nzFdb7/ibm-db/setup.py", line 149, in <module>
easy_cli_path = os.path.join(tmp_path, 'ibm_db-%s.egg' % ("-".join([VERSION, "py"+sys.version.split(" ")[0][0:3]]) if('win32' in sys.platform) else "-".join([VERSION, "py"+sys.version.split(" ")[0][0:3], os_, arch_])), 'clidriver')

NameError: name 'arch_' is not defined

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nzFdb7/ibm-db
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Can anybody help me or give me an advice?

I'm getting frustated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Informix Client SDK on Raspberry pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043481/installing-informix-client-sdk-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: The raspberry os is ARM based, you can edit the ibm_db setup.py to define value "arch_" on arm platform.
I have tried, but it's also not succeed. By Google, perhaps it's because that ibm_db is not work on ARM.